# Function for counting string length doesn't work

Tags: c

I have this code

```
int conta(char *A){
   int i = 0;
   while (A[i] != "\0"){
       i = i+1;
   }
   return i;
}
```

but this sends me a warning "Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified". Is this only a problem of Xcode? Because i've seen this exact same code on working on a Windows compiler.

Comment: "\0" is a string literal, '\0' is the null character. You could even compare as in `while (A[i] != 0)` or `while (A[i])`.

Comment: "i've seen this exact same code on working on a Windows compiler" No, you haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"\0" is a indeed a string literal. I guess you mean comparing character values to '\0' instead.